# How to customize ItemExporter to not override output file on Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Im writing a simple web crawler with scrapy that capture data from two different websites. You can find all my files [here](https://github.com/tamercuba/Web-Crawler).

Basically I have a `main.py` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import scrapy
from app.spiders.spider_maquinas import VultrSpider, DigitalOceanSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        settings = get_project_settings()
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
        process.crawl(VultrSpider())
        process.crawl(DigitalOceanSpider())
        process.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
```

And this pipelines for my two spiders:

```
import json
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter, CsvItemExporter

class CustomJsonExporter(JsonItemExporter):
    def _beautify_newline(self):
        self.file.write(b'\n')

class PrintItem:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print(dict(item))
        return item

class JsonPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file       = open('static/maquinas.json', 'wb')
        self.exporter   = CustomJsonExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

class CsvPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file       = open('static/maquinas.csv', 'wb')
        self.exporter   = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.fields_to_export = ['storage', 'cpu', 'memory', 'bandwidth', 'price']

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

But the second spider override the first values. I need to write new Pipelines changing this manually to now override the data or there is an easy way to do this ? Thank you!